# Getting len(a) of a list a imported from a file in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

This should work just fine. I cannot understand why I am getting this result, though. I have a programme, which opens a text file.

```
file2 = open('file.txt','r')
```

The text file contains 5 lines. To put them into a list, I do:

```
data2 = file2.readlines()
```

Then, I can make a variable containing the third line by doing so:

```
var = data2[2]
```

The third line of the text file contains a list, with numbers from 1-12, each one being a seperate string.

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
```

Finally, I print the length of the list,

```
print len(var)
```

Instead of getting 12, I get 53. I even tried that:

```
print len(data2[2])
```

Which apparently didn't work. Any explaination?

Comment: Try `','.split(data2[2])` (or whatever delimiter you need)

Comment: Hmm.. seems to give me 53, still...

Comment: Should be easy to parse but you haven't given any details

Comment: Actually, I got it right. I changed the third line to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12. Then I did as you said. Works well.

Comment: I was getting `.split()` and `.join()` confused for a second and made a typo. You need to call .split() on the string and pass it the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data2[2]` is a string in the provided example. It has 53 characters in it. You will need to convert it to an array by some kind of string manipulation/parsing.

Comment: Oh, I see. That is the problem. I should have realized that, it is because I take it from another list. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
>>> line = "['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'] "
>>> len(line)
53
>>> line = line.strip()
>>> line = line.replace('[','')
>>> line = line.replace(']','')
>>> line = line.replace("'","")
>>> line
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12'
>>> nums = [int(s) for s in line.split(',')]
>>> nums
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> len(nums)
12
```